# Multiple conditions with if in shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I want to check if a file exists or not along with the no of lines = 4 in a single if condition . Can anyone help here.

```
if [[ -f report]] && [[`wc -l report` -eq 4 ]]; then
    echo " Proceed further"
else
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/ will tell you what's wrong with your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

This is simpler:

```
{ [ `wc -l < report` -eq 4 ] || exit; } 2>/dev/null 
echo " Proceed further"
```

Notes:

- If *report* exists and is *4* lines long, then `wc -l report`
  returns:

  ```
  4 report
  ```

  ...which `-eq` can't understand.  Instead do `wc -l < report` which
  outputs an `-eq`-friendly:

  ```
  4
  ```
- There's no need to check if *report* exists, since the `<` redirection
  will do that anyway, and returns the same error code.
- More specific exit codes.  If *report* does not exist, the exit code is *2*.  If *report* is *5* lines long, the exit code is *1*.

Comment: My objective here is to exit from script if the count is not equals to 4. How to add that

Comment: @John, see revised answer.

Comment: @John, Ahem! [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)